# Node selector or taint have more precedence?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

we have an aks cluster and having one system nodepool and 2 user nodepools (usnp1&usnp2) currently. We have multiple applications pods currently running across the usernodepools.

So now we have a requirement to run one of our existing application pods to dedicately have a seperate nodepool and namespace seperately. Example, our application myapp is currently running in namespace "all-app-ns" which has nodeselector set "usnp1", and in the same pool we have other application pods also. So need to move the myapp pods and all related components completely to new namespace specifically for "myapp-ns" and it should be allocated only specific to "myapp-pool"

1. The myapp-pool" should not allocate any other pods than the myapp. Which option will be more precedence here - node selector with pods or taints? i read like nodeselector will force the scheduler "should assign" to specic node, where taint will do "can assign".. so nodeselector will be better option?
2. since myapp deployment and pods are already running currently in "all-app-ns", whether moving those to new namespace "myapp-ns",  will these delete existing myapp pods in the namespace -all-app-ns"? will this make any downtime? currentlt we deployed this using helm chart and will the helmstate will delete the old pods and create the newpods, and any downtime will happen ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. > ... so nodeselector will be a better option?

You could use nodeSelector but also nodeAffinity. It is just a matter of configuration. The nodeSelector strictly define that the Pod with e.g

```
nodeSelector:
   usnp1: "true"
```

could only be deployed to node with label `usnp1=true`.
But you could define same with nodeAffinity in Pod configuration e.g

```
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: <your-pod-name>
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: usnp1
            operator: In
            values:
            - "true"
```

Those configurations are equal.

2. > ... and any downtime will happen?

If I understand clearly, you need to move `myapp pods` which are currently deployed in `all-app-ns` to `myapp-ns`. So in this scenario, if you are deploying to the different namespace in your case `myapp-ns`, the pods in `all-app-ns` will not be undeployed. I suppose, because in `helm install` you need to define the `--namespace` option if you are not already switched with `kubectl set-context`. So to undeploy you have to `helm uninstall <RELEASE> --namespace=all-app-ns`. The availability of the application depends on your DNS records, so you will probably need to configure them if you need to expose the app publicly.

---

To answer your questions bellow:

> so for point1. if we have any pods without any nodeselector defined,
> there will be chance to allocate that pods to the new nodepool in this
> cae right ? the aim here is not allow the new nodepools to have any
> other pods otherthan the myapp pods. whether taint will help is this
> scenario than nodeselctor or a admission controller called
> "podnodeselector" ?

Use `nodeAffinity` configuration desribed above for `myapp` pod configuration.

Add the label to `myapp` pod configuration e.g

```
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        usnp1: myapp
```

For any other pods which you do not want to be scheduled at that node, or better say not scheduled with pods which have a label `usnp1: myapp` create `podAntiAffinity` configuration e.g

```
  affinity:
    podAntiAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: usnp1
            operator: In
            values:
            - myapp
        topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
```

Look at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/

Anyway this also doesn't to be 100% solution, because scheduling of pods is complex algorithm with many rules, which are score weighted. You could see the score and weights in schedulerds log.

Look at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/kube-scheduler/

> Also for point2- we will be proceeding with helm upgrade with the
> modified manifests with the namespace changes from pipeline, in that
> case whether the helm statefile play a role here to delete the old
> pods?

To this, I don't know about a functionality in helm where you could parallel undeploy from one namespace and deploy to second namespace. Because if I understand clearly the state of deployment applied by `helm install` is per namespace. So to deploy/undeploy you need to always define `--namespace` if you are not already switched in. And that probably means that you couldn't interfere with namespace state when deploying same helm chart.

But I'm do not have much experiences with helm.

Comment: so for point1.  if we have any pods without any nodeselector defined, there will be chance to allocate that pods to the new nodepool in this cae right ? the aim here is not allow the new nodepools to have any other pods otherthan the myapp pods.  whether taint will help is this scenario than nodeselctor or a admission controller called "podnodeselector" ?

Comment: Also for point2-  we will be proceeding with helm upgrade with the modified manifests with the namespace changes from pipeline, in that case whether the helm statefile play a role here to delete the old pods?